# How to fix this error with my code? Type error cannot read property of null?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

At the moment when I run my code I get a 'cannot read property 'age' of null and it breaks my code, how do I put a check in place so it only runs when I'm signed in? I thought I did this using routing but apparently not

code from routing on App.js page: on this page the authentication is checked by firebase and elements are conditionally rendered to the DOM also the User_data is also pulled from the database and stored to internal storage where its is called upon later on the main page.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    }
    this.authListener = this.authListener.bind(this);
  }

 //onload runs funtion to check for authenication from firebase
  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

//checks firebase for authentication
  authListener() {
    Authentication.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
        localStorage.setItem('user', user.uid);
        this.pulldata_Health();
        this.pulldata_Meals();
        this.pulldata_Ingredients();
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null })
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
      }
    });
  }

  //connects to database and stores data to local storage
  pulldata_Health() {
    database.collection('Health_data')
      .doc(localStorage.getItem('user'))
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data')))
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error reading health", error);
      });

  }

 render() {
    //reders different elements depding on authenticaion and if sidedrawer is open
    let backdrop;
    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />
    };

    return (
      <div className="App_margin">
        <Router>
          <div className='App'>
            {this.state.user ? (<Nav drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />) : (<Login_bar />)}
            <SideDrawer sidedrawerClickHandler={this.sidedrawerToggleClickHandler} show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
            {backdrop}

            {this.state.user ? (
              < Switch >
                <Route path='/setup_page' component={setup_page} exact />,
                <Route path='/settings_page' component={settings_page} exact />,
                <Route path='/' component={Main_page} />
              </Switch>
            ) : (<Login_page/>)}


          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Code for my main page component causing issues: when some user data is stored once it stops the issue, even upon logout. so I need to find a way of to stop this function being called as soon as the app loads but I'm unsure how to do this was wondering if I could use user state as a condition again but I think this would cause the same issue?

```
const healthData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'));
        console.log(healthData);
        return (
            <div className='main_Main'>
                <div className='meal_divs'>
                    <p className='food_heading'>Status:</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your age is: { healthData.age }</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your gender is: {healthData.gender}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your goal is: {healthData.goal}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your height is: {healthData.height}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>your weight is: {healthData.weight}</p>
                </div>
```

Any thoughts help would be greatly appreciated idk how to fix this[image]

Update 25/03/2020:

I initially just added the previously mentioned code below which did fix the main error I started this thread for

```
return healthData == null ? "" : (
            <div className='main_Main'>...
```

this stoped the elements being rendered after login unless a hard rest was users once logged in.
I then used a componentDidMount() function to pull user_data from local storage which fixed the HTML elements not rendering once logged in but now the user data doesn't display unless I hard resset once logged in (Ctrl+R) anyone know how to fix? this is the current code.

```
  constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                healthData: {}
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.state.healthData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'))
        }


        render() {
            //gets users data and renders it to <p> items
            const healthData = this.state.healthData;
            console.log(healthData);
            return healthData == null ? "" : (
                <div className='main_Main'>
                    <div className='meal_divs'>
                        <p className='food_heading'>Status:</p>
                        <p className='food_text'>Your age is: {this.state.healthData.age}</p>
                        <p className='food_text'>Your gender is: {healthData.gender}</p>
                        <p className='food_text'>Your goal is: {healthData.goal}</p>
                        <p className='food_text'>Your height is: {healthData.height}</p>
                        <p className='food_text'>your weight is: {healthData.weight}</p>
                    </div>
```

so its the {healthData} that's not rendering upon sign in now please help thanks

Update 12:02 25/03/2020:
The only reason the Html elements were rendering is because I set the state of healthData as {} which is no longer null but the {} was still empty when I set the state as Null or undefined at the start I had the same problem.

Comment: sorry if the gramma is off its late and I'm very tired lol

Comment: Can you use 
return healthData == null ? "" : 
            (<div className='main_Main'>********

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath Hi anthony thanks for your help this works and fixes the login, but the only problem I seem to be having is that it doesn't appear to be rendering upon login into the site as on load the user_data remains null, I'm going to try a componentDidMount() on the main page to get the user_data and will report back

Comment: @lukeet To have a nice experience as a beginner on Stackoverflow try asking very precise and to the point question. Not multiple debugging related issues

Comment: For example a good question here would be like: You did setup you state “some code”, then you render the value in state “some code”, then you update the state “some code”, But state doesn’t update.

Comment: But there are already alot of such questions on Stackoverflow already, so you won’t have to ask it in the first place. In sort divide up your issues in very small chunks then go through the workflow of your code if it doesn’t work then ask a question

Answer (score 0):

According to flow in react

Why dont you do this in constructor?

```
 constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    healthData:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data')) 
                }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //in case you are updating user_data somewhere
       this.setState({ 
        healthData:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'))});
      }
  render(){
                //gets users data and renders it to <p> items
                const healthData = this.state.healthData;
                console.log(healthData);
                return healthData == null ? "" : (
                    <div className='main_Main'>
                        <div className='meal_divs'>
                            <p className='food_heading'>Status:</p>
                            <p className='food_text'>Your age is: {healthData.age}</p>
                            <p className='food_text'>Your gender is: {healthData.gender}</p>
                            <p className='food_text'>Your goal is: {healthData.goal}</p>
                            <p className='food_text'>Your height is: {healthData.height}</p>
                            <p className='food_text'>your weight is: {healthData.weight}</p>
                        </div>
                       )
             }
```

Comment: thanks I will try this but doesn't that make the const health data redundant?

Comment: you can directly use "this.state.healthData"

Comment: just realised the reason setting in the constructor doesn't work and I didnt use it is because the login page is routed / at start with no user found this mean the constructor is monentarily run without user_data returning null that's why its undefined upon load but idk how to fix thanks though

Comment: Hey did you try using this.setState in component did mount...you should not directly write this.state.something="something"

Comment: yes funnily enough just added that it didn't change anything though but defiantly improved my code

Comment: in pulldata_health function , what is the log of console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data')))

Comment: "{age: "20", gender: "male", goal: "recomp", height: "158", weight: "80"}" as soon as logged in but the main page is still null until hard refresh

Comment: https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/612

Comment: thanks just had a read through but nothing is wrong with the routing I just checked using the react chrome module main_page is pushed to the DOM but its internal elements are not rendered because healthdata is null unless a hard reset is used

Comment: somewhere you are setting user_data to null which makes the things not work

Comment: I remove local user_data when the user logs out it is pulled again on App.js upon login  where its restored to local storage